# How to run double main in same project?

Tags: test

I imported unity test harness to my project and seperated them from my production codes. As you know, there is a main belongs to my project and there should be another main to run tests. If I try to compile , I am getting duplicate main definition of course. I am currently reading @jamesgreenings book and I came to till chapter 3 and passed two examples. I did not see yet about how to handle this problem.

Comment: You could put your production `main()` and your test `main()` in different .c files and then only include either one in the project to be built. You could also put them both in the same file and then use `#ifdef` macros to conditionally compile one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

Since you use a variant of Eclipse IDE, you want to add a build target with the name of "Test" or "Debug" and then just choose if you want to build the standard  default production code target or the test/debug target. Then configure the build targets that one of them you compile in one file and exclude another file, if you have two files. Or if they are in same file, you can use a define to know which target is being built.

Comment: Yes that is what I want to do but I couldn't. As doing this, is necessary to add another gcc for test ? As I look up the internet to find solution, some one was adding cygwin to ide and doing quite complicated things. These integrating phases make me tired. I want to pass this stage as fast as.

Comment: Why would you need another GCC compiler or Cygwin for this? Why google around for random info when you have manuals, tutorials etc? You literally need to find the correct menu to add a build target, unless you already have two build targets. Yes, the Eclipse based IDE has a steep learning curve, it is complex and unintuitive if you are new to it and if you come from simpler IDEs, be prepared spend lots of time figuring out how to do a simple thing but not finding where the setting is and how it is supposed to work due to how Eclipse wants it to be done.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are compeletely right.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to run two different sections based on if production or testing, you want your main code to be a simple if then else then, and your production code is one function and your test another function.

Ex pseudo code:

```
precode (){
  variable a = "test"
}

productionCode (){
  do that thing
}

testCode (){
  don't do that thing
}

main (){
  if a = "test"; then
     testCode();
  else
     productionCode();
 loop to main;
}
```

Otherwise just have two copies of your project.

Comment: Let me write what I understood. A varible defines which one gonna compile and debug. It changes the targets. If that variable is test, main loop belongs to tests will run, otherwise, production does. So, how can I change content of variable a automatically at each time ?

Comment: Automatically? As in not based on changing the code, but after its been programmed? You could put the device in a test mode by dedicating a GPIO as a "enable test mode" pin. So "if pin 5 = high; then testcode()"

Comment: I try to mean that I do not want to change content of that variable whenever I want to pass one state from another. It will be better by doing it autonomously. To set gpio means running on target hardware. I dont want this. At that book , James mentioned about create another makefile to seperate directory and run seperately. I dont have enough capability on subjects like these. So is it possible ? @Passerby

Comment: What you want to do then would be a general function of your IDE. Or as he mentions about "create another makefile" simply means have two copies of your project/code.

Comment: I have an ongoing project at ST Cube IDE based on eclipse and I started to learn unit test method. I imported unity to my project and created test file for functions will be tested. I just want to test functions and if they pass, copy into production codes. I also want to embed production codes into mcu whenever I want. So two copy means there should be two project which one is for test and another is for one production codes that is whatever I want to do with those? @Passerby

Comment: Yes, thats the idea.

Comment: Okey but this idea does not meet my problem. In my opinion, to keep seperate them makes hard to watch and imposible to manage version control

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would be better done with preprocessor commands. `#DEFINE debug` and `#IFDEF debug` and `#IFNDEF debug`, and so on.

Comment: @Hearth At this case, I have to change content of #define manually  whenever I want to switch one case to another right ? I just want to do it autonomously.